# Can not import submodule

Tags: c++, clang++, c++-modules

On `clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)` I can not import `std` submodules like `std.vector`. Whole `import std` works fine, but `import std.vector` not. I'm using `libc++` modulemap which define this module properly.

## Edit

Same problem exists with custom modulemap

```
module test {
  explicit module sub {
    header "test.hpp"
    export *
  }
}
```

It can not load module `test.sub` but reports that symbol `foo` could be find in it.

## Edit 2

`clang 5.0.2` behaves in same way.

## Edit 3

`6.0.1-rc1` same

**Is there any issue releated to that or infirmation that it is not yet supported?**

Comment: Are you supposed to be able to import those modules? Has Clang implemented such support? Is there even a standard defining how the standard library will be modularized?

Comment: @NicolBolas  Yes, it is published as ISO/IEC TS 21544:2018 and modules are described in https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/module.modulemap the problem is that clang refuses to finnd such submodule

Comment: That TS does not modularize the standard library; it merely defines how modules as a feature work.

Comment: It is not the point how std library will be modularized, but how to push clang to import submodule

Comment: My question is whether `std.vector` is actually a module that exists in Clang's implementation.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes it is. Same case with `test.sub` from example above.

Answer (score 0):

For import modules or sub-modules, clang 6 does not work perfectly everywhere, clang 7 will be improved in the future.

You can try to set `-fmodules-cache-path=<your-cache-path>` flag explicitly, and you can see that, if there is some module involved the build, clang will populate the pre-compiled module files (normally `*.pcm`) to it when it builds.

In clang 7 documentation, you can practice [Module Map Language](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language) to create your own modules to include some headers and export them, then import your own modules. As the documentation described, it is not stable now. You need to try.

At least for this moment you can use `import std` as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Thx, for _edit 1_ example only `test-2ZVJ6VLHGNNX8.pcm` file is created.

Comment: The problem is that OI'm trying to modularize some library with modulemap file, but it includes `<algorithm>`. Compiler translates it to `import std.alhotithm` and fails on it.

Comment: I think this link will give you some hints: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2014-October/039434.html

Comment: so, still no `.`  import then?